# Use App Engine Modules to run cron job in F1 instance class

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a frequent cron job in my app on google app engine standard, and it's using tons of instance hours to perform a quick task. I find that the instance hours problem goes away if I switch the app to `F1` in `app.yaml`, but the web front-end needs more power (been using `F4_1G`).

It seems like a simple solution would be to use [App Engine Modules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/an-overview-of-app-engine) to run the cron job on `F1` while keeping the rest of the app on `F4_1G`, but the documentation is short on actual code. Can somebody please show how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't actually require code changes, it's controlled by your projects configuration (yaml) files.

You create a service (formerly module) by specifying it in a separate .yaml file, deploying the service, and then telling your cron job to run on that service.

Let's assume you want to create a service called "lightweight".

Start by copying your existing app.yaml to lightweight.yaml, 
add (or modify) the "service" line to read "service: lightweight", and update the application instance to f1.

Optionally, clean up the handlers so that only the ones you need for your cron instance are present

eg, lightweight.yaml:

```
application: yourapp
service: lightweight
version: 0-4
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true    

instance_class: F1

handlers:
-  url: /mycronjob
   script: main.app
   login: admin
```

Then, in your cron.yaml, specify the service as your target.

```
cron:
- description: example
  url: /mycronjob 
  schedule: every 5 minutes
  target: lightweight
```

Once that is done, deploy lightweight.yaml and cron using gcloud or appcfg.

Once deployed, your cron job will run on the lightweight service, using an f1 instance.  You can also access the lightweight service directly in your browser lightweight.yourapp.appspot.com